# My objective is to merge the two queries. I'm having discrepancies in executing in separate manner

Tags: mysql

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7m8Gy.jpg)[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fD1Yi.jpg)Help me to merge these 2 given queries

```
SELECT DISTINCT vehicle_no FROM petty_cash;

SELECT COUNT(variation) as bal FROM petty_cash WHERE variation<0;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What would your desired output look like?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT vehicle_no, COUNT(variation) as bal FROM petty_cash WHERE variation < 0;
try this

Comment: if variation is zero i just want to hide the row. I'm executing as separate query. So i can't achieve the desired output. Help me to merge and to execute it as a single query

Comment: how would you like to merge the results ? Two rows ? or one row two columns ?

Comment: help me to merge the two queries as one query

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your output but i can combine those 2 queries as below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT vehicle_no, COUNT(variation) as bal FROM petty_cash WHERE variation < 0;
```

Comment: This not works. As i use distinct it prints only one vehicle number.

Comment: post your required output

Comment: it will print onlly one vehicle number cause you used distinct and if variation < 0 for that number @GaneshKumar

Comment: I just want to hide the row if variation is zero.

Comment: Vehicle No No of Variation
Py01CA2652 0 
Py01CA2651 1

Comment: variation < 0 does not become true on your database

Comment: because values of variation are 0 or > 0

Comment: actually i mean bal variable.       https://i.stack.imgur.com/fD1Yi.jpg

Comment: yes the count(variation) return 2 coz you have 2 records of variation

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to execute two statment in one query? Is answer is yes then it

```
SELECT  (
  SELECT DISTINCT vehicle_no FROM petty_cash       
) AS firstStatment,
(
 SELECT COUNT(variation) as bal FROM petty_cash WHERE variation<0
) AS secondStatment
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use case to get your desired result,

like,

```
SELECT DISTINCT vehicle_no,CASE WHEN variation==0 THEN 'HIDE ROW' END FROM petty_cash;
```

After executing this query you can get the number of vehicle with HIDE ROW value where variation is zero.
In the place of 'HIDE ROW' you can set 0 or 1 for your understanding.

I Hope this will help you.